# RLC circuit: unexpected behaviour

Tags: passive-networks, back-emf, current-sink

I see some unexpected behaviour from (what I thought) is a relative straight forward RLC oscillator circuit:
[image: circuit]

The idea is that a coil is charged over a certain period of time (during this pulse the current is rising), and the RLC circuit (R12 L1 and C5) is then isolated quickly by two MOSFETs with large enough break-down voltages to withstand back-emf. The generated large back-emf then drives the oscillator and current is measured over a (22 mOhm) sense resistor. The differential amplifiers are just there to condition the signal to input into a 12 bit, 3.3V ADC. A LTspice simulation agrees with my expectation to see a damped oscillation. However, what I observe experimentally with the circuit with three different pulse lengths (25us black, 50us red and 100us blue) is the following:
[image: result]

While the pulse length and the current peak in the inital oscillation seem to be ok and the oscillation frequency is correct within error of the inductor and capacitor, between about 15-35us current is sunk to the same level in all three cases. This is the zoom-in:
[image: result-zoom]

Can someone please explain what could be happening here? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You must have the wrong colours. When I simulated it, the colours were pink, yellow and magenta.

Comment: Looks like your pulse lengths are too long. Period of oscillation looks to be about 23 uS. Pulse "ON" period should be less than half that... < 12 uS.

Comment: @glen_geek: What I called pulse is just the time period before the MOSFETs isolate the RLC circuit. It's the time to allow the build-up of current flowing through the inductor, and is not limited by the oscillator frequency.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend inserting series elements - like 100R resistors - in the FET gate connections so you can monitor the gate waveforms.

I suspect the FETs aren't turning off instantaneously and that during that time, the inductor current returns to one of the supply rails.

Also split the sense R into two, keep one where it is, put the other in series with the inductor, and monitor both currents.

I think you'll see a positive spike in the inductor current that isn't in the capacitor current, while the slower of the FETs is still turning off. That's probably M2, returning current to the +ve rail.

If so, you can work on improving the gate drive waveforms.

Comment: Thanks Brian, indeed very helpful (tried to upvote but as newbie I'm not allowed). Didn't mention that the mosfets are driven (mcp1407 with 0.1, 1uF caps nearby). There's a 2nd resistor after the low side mosfet and it looks like it gates properly. 2 more question: 1) If the current returns to the positive supply rail, would you expect it to happen slowly (t const of cap)? 2) Why are the first oscillation and the other oscillations not synchronized? I would have thought the oscillation would just continue but appear damped because of the current loss. Thanks in advance for further help.

Comment: The low side resistor won't tell you anything about the high side transistor. If you don't want to try the earlier experiment, try a high side sensing resistor as well. Without that and gate voltages, anything further on my part would just be guesswork.